# Admin Website for CRUD operations on Azure Mobile Services

Tags: asp.net, crud, azure-mobile-services

I'm attempting to build a simple app and would like to take advantage of Azure Mobile Services for authentication and storage of user info and settings...

however I also have some application data that I need to store, which I figure I should also put into the mobile services tables.

However, there doesn't appear to be any administrative interface for managing the data in Azure Mobile Services, such as CRUD to fill the tables and manage the read-only data that the users would be accessing.

So my options are either to put this data in a separate website/database, create a separate website and use azure mobile services within to manage the data as an admin, or just put everything into my own asp.net website and use web api (or something similar) to serve the data to the apps.

obviously the last option offers the most flexibility, but my ideal option is to be able to simply manage the data as an admin with another website.

the data i need to manage is not something the users will be editing or adding to through the app, but rather data that I need to have already in the app for the users to access...

what do you think is my best option based on these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different options for pure data management.  First I'd say though that whatever option you choose, I would recommend keeping the data in the same database or make it otherwise accessible to your Mobile Service.  If you're comfortable with doing it in SQL, you can connect to the database your Mobile Service is using with SQL Management Studio (this is the windows utility for SQL DB administration) or there is the SQL Portal which is a Silverlight tool which offers a lot of the functionality of SQL Management Studio.  Moving on from pre-built tools, you can build your own app / website which interacts with the database directly (or through Mobile Services as an Admin).  This would be the most work but offers you the ability to customize anything you might need.  Lastly, you can just use a REST Client to handle dealing with any admin data.  Since everything is exposed in Mobile Services via a REST API, you can use a REST Client (like Postman) to directly post data to your Mobile Service (using the Master Key to come across as an admin if needed).  This is arguably the easiest way to do it without a SQL tool though it's more drudge work since you need to enter the JSON text for any data you want to send up.